# prepend title tag to dom with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to prepend the title of a hyperlink to a dom-element, but it does not show up there

html

```
<ul class="grid effect-4" id="filter">
<li><a href="#" title="Klimaat" data-group="red"><img src="klimaat.png" /></a></li>
</ul>           

<p class="float-left">Filter:</p>
```

Javascript

```
$("ul#filter li a").on("click", function(){    

      var title = $(this).attr('title');

      $(".float-left").prepend(title);

     }, function() {
                // out code

});
```

Comment: what is the role of the last argument (a function) passed in `.on()`?

Comment: @KingKing It's the function that's run when the event occurs.

Comment: @Barmar omg, I meant the last argument

Comment: @KingKing Good question! There should only be one function argument to `.on()`. Mark, what do you mean by `out code`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
$(".float-left").text("Filter:"+title);
```

Comment: is it possible to clear previous prepends. With many hyperlinks it keeps adding them onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong javascript function structure. You are passing two handler but you are supposed to pass one. See the syntax for jQuery on function [.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

*Replace*

```
, function() {
                // out code

});
```

*With*

```
);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/44DyX/)**

```
$("ul#filter li a").on("click", function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(".float-left").prepend(title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Works here : http://jsfiddle.net/X5aSL/1/

```
$("#filter li a").on("click", function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(".float-left").prepend(title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this prepend method is always work when you click the link so i more love to use html

```
$("ul#filter li a").on("click", function () {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(".float-left").html(title);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44DyX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
     $("ul#filter li a").click( function(){    

     var title = $(this).attr('title');

      $(".float-left").prepend(title);

     });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/Ezvnp/4/)